# Can I detect when requirejs generates script errors due to user navigation before all specified modules are loaded?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, loading

I've overridden the onError function to log back to our server whenever the browser detects client side errors. This helps us catch JavaScript crashes that may be affecting our app and is super useful.

However, onError gets triggered like crazy by requirejs if the user navigates away before requirejs is done loading all its modules. Easy way to reproduce is to load one of our pages, then navigate away quickly before everything is done loading.

I am wondering if there is any way to check for these errors that are due to the user navigating away?

Here's an example:

[image: requirejs error example]
Any insights would be very much appreciated.

Comment: was my comment helpful? Did you figure it out?

Comment: It sounds promising, I haven't had a chance to give it a shot yet, will let you know as soon as I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way that I would go about it is like this...

Since we don't want to log errors caused by the user navigating away from the page, we need to be able to determine if we can detect when a user is leaving a page... Turns out we can, by using the beforeunload event of the window object. What I would do on window.beforeunload is simply remove the event listener/handler for the requirejs onError event.